# !how to enable workspace window and view projects in eclipse for java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a few projects but now I don't know how to view and also I don't see any menu bar! I used to have work space,what might be wrong? please help.

EDIT : I already mentioned I am not even able to see menu bar! so, no window or no FILE dropdown also! the eclipse is just opening and i can add project and other save print button are disabled, apart from save,forward backward disabled buttons , I am not able to see anything?! what to do?

Also actually I have installed two JRE's and I have eclipse and eclipse for java ee also on the same machine, i recently installed java ee eclipse and jre 1.7 for some requirement, earlier I used to work with just eclipse and jre 1.8. I am not even java developer, but for some course, i need to install 1.7 jre and eclipse java ee! Now what might be the problem?

Comment: To view projects either you can use Project Explorer or Package Explorer. Click Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i dont even have reputation to post a screenshot :( please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally switched your workspace.
Go to `File->Switch Workspace` to check your recent workspaces, and change it back.

Answer (score 0):

go in window menu and click on reset perspective and if your project are still not seen then try to switch the workspace to the drive in which it is saved